# Removing 'src' attribute from output of $html->image() in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, lazy-loading, cakephp-1.2, jquery-lazyload

I am using CakePHP 1.2. I am trying to use jQuery Lazy (http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_basic-usage) from CakePHP. Reading the documentation at https://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/HTML.html#image, it shows how

```
<?php echo $html->image('cake_logo.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP'))?>
```

produces the following output:

```
<img src="/img/cake_logo.png" alt="CakePHP" />
```

I need to produce this output:

```
<img class="lazy" data-src="/img/cake_logo.png" />
```

How can I do that using `$html->image()` in CakePHP 1.2? The problem is that in the syntax `image(string $path, array $htmlAttributes = array())`, the first parameter is mandatory and in the output it produces the `src=...` attribute of `img`. I need to have an output with `<img... />` that does not contain the `src=...` attribute. How could I achieve that using $html->image() in CakePHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the built-in HTML helper it's not possible without modifying the tag template. So if you need lazy loading on all images, then you could for example change the `image` tag template to something like:

```
<img class="lazy" data-src="%s" %s/>
```

However this would clash with using the `class` attribute. So alternatively you could extend the HTML helper and implement a custom `image()` method (or an additional method). Here's a quick & dirty example, which should be pretty self-explantory:

```
function image($path, $options = array())
{
    $defaults = array(
        'class' => null
    );
    $options += $defaults;

    $options['class'] = 'lazy ' . $options['class'];

    $originalTemplate = $this->tags['image'];
    $this->tags['image'] = '<img data-src="%s" %s/>';

    $imageHtml = parent::image($path, $options);

    $this->tags['image'] = $originalTemplate;

    return $imageHtml;
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Core Helpers > HTML > Changing the tags output by HtmlHelper](https://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/HTML.html#changing-the-tags-output-by-htmlhelper)**
- **[Cookbook > Developing With CakePHP > Helpers > Creating Helpers](https://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Helpers.html#creating-helpers)**

Comment: How can be justified modifying the template or extending the HTML helper instead of of just using this directly?: `<img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $imageUrl;?>" />`. Security, scalability,...? What would be the main benefit of "doing it the CakePHP way"? It looks straightforward to simply use pure PHP/HTML code: `<img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $imageUrl;?>" />`.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya The main benefit is the underlying path management, ie the helper will create the correct path irrespectively of your applications base path, it supports theme assets, and timestamping. Also using standard CakePHP code makes refactoring easier.